# How to set frame rate to 25 FPS as default?

Tags: customization, scene, frame-rate

Is it possible to set a default frame rate to Blender? I usually use 25 frame per second. If I started a new scene it would be useful to have 25 FPS as default.

Comment: Side note, if you want to do it in a script you can use (in Blender 2.83 at least): `bpy.context.scene.render.fps = 25`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just change your default `.blend` file. In a new Blender window, change the default framerate, then go to *File* > *Save Startup File* or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Setting to desired framerate and saving startup file doesn't work for creating new scene. Creating new scene will always default to 24p.